# How do I check if my string ends with WA followed by 9 digit

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, validation, yup

I want to validate my string input with regx in typescript/javascript.

string input is 9 digit followed by WA

I tried using below two Regx, its able to validate digit part, but couldn't validate end of string to be WA.

```
val.matches('^[0-9]') && val.matches("WA$") 
val.matches('^[0-9]WA$')
```

Comment: Use '\d{9}WA$' as regexp

Comment: looks like regx was correct, I was using it incorrectly in context of YUP library.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex approach with `test()`:

```js
var input = "text 123456789wa";
if (/\d{9}WA$/i.test(input)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

Comment: If you need to make sure a string contains only 9 digits followed by WA, you can use this regexp: `/^\d{9}WA$/`

Comment: @sneas I actually see 2 (3?) problem descriptions, between the title and question, but I welcome your comment because it covers one of the other question readings.

Comment: also how can I make WA case-insensitive?

Comment: @KrunalParmar Hi, just use the `/i` flag at the end of the regex pattern, `i` is short for case insensitive, check the updated answer.